# Jquery stop event after running once

Tags: jquery, events, click

how can i stop a click event after running once (so it can be clicked only once and then stop)

i tried with

```
(".button_no_false").disable();
```

..stop ..stop.event and so on but wont work only thing is that the script wont finish
how can i stop it cause if i click again it looks terrible and the image is missing

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    // Anfang Dokument Ready Funktion

    $("#button_yes").click(function (event) {  // Anfang Klick Funktion
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).html();    // Inhalt in Klickfunktion
        $(this).hide(); // Gedrückten Button nach Klicken verstecken
        $(".button_no").hide(); // Aktiven Button verstecken
        $(".button_no_false").show(); // Fake Button

        // Beginn Ajax Segment mit Angabe von Typ Url Data und Div #ausgabe
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://domain.de/functions/script.php',
            data: {id : <?php echo $id ?>},
            success: function(data){
                $('#ausgabe_yes').html(data);
            } 
        });     // Ende Ajax Segment  
    });    // Ende Klick Funktion
});  // Ende Dokument Ready Funktion
</script>
```

kind regards

Comment: You want to execute it one until it works or one even if the ajax call fails?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) :

```
$("button").one('click', function () { console.log('Will fire only one time'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function.

```
$('#button_yes').off("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's one() method. See http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. this is a jquery  example. this will run once an even**

```
 $( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
    alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
 });


 $( "body" ).one( "click", "#foo", function() {
    alert( "This displays if #foo is the first thing clicked in the body." );
 });
```